# JQuery count the number of items serialize

Tags: jquery

After "serialize" i have this string:

```
attrac[]=2&attrac[]=1&attrac[]=3&attrac[]=44&attrac[]=1&attrac[]=2
```

Is there any command that count the number of items in it?

In the example above i have 6 items

the serialize come from this code:

```
var attrac = $("#sec"+secID).sortable('serialize', {
  attribute: "data-id"
});
```